# Copy NSTableView row greyed out

Tags: swift, macos, copy, nstableview, nscopying

I would like to add copy (Command + C) functionality to my NSTableView for a row (or multiple rows) that the user has selected. Based on what I read the copy functionality in the Menu Item should be active automatically if you implement copy in your TableView Controller [Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html).

I've tried adding in the NSTableViewController (is the delegate and data source of the table view) the following things with no luck, the copy menu item still appears greyed out:

1. override func copy() -> AnyObject {
       print("TEST: copytriggered") /*Here i would copy to clipboard the selected rows*/
       return true
   }

2.
Conforming to NSCopying, implementing copyWithZone...

3.
Trying 1 and 2 in the window controller and app delegate.

4. Adding func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
   pasteboardWriterForRow row: Int) -> NSPasteboardWriting? in the TableView data source.

I have no clue what to do at this point, any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the answer, publishing here for future reference.

You are confusing the Copy edit action method with the methods for making a duplicate of an object.  The NSCopying protocol and the copyWithZone() method are for the latter, enabling an object to create a copy of itself.  Likewise, the copy() method is just a convenience cover method for copyWithZone().

The action method for the Copy edit menu item is subtly different.  It's "func copy(_ sender: AnyObject?)".  That's the general form for all action methods, taking a sender argument and not returning anything.  You need to implement that method.

Finally, tableView(_:pasteboardWriterForRow:) is generally only used for drag-and-drop, when the user drags a row.

Comment: With Swift, remember to proceed your declaration with @objc – `@objc func copy(_ sender: AnyObject) {}`